# Merge multiple csv files using Perl

Tags: perl, csv, merge

I am new to Perl so sorry for the simple question.

I have a Perl script that produces 7 csv files. All these files have 8 common column headings.

The file names will be constant, each file only has 8 columns and there will always be data in each value for each column.

The file size for each is never bigger than 400k.

I would like to combine these csv files into one file using Perl. The output will have the same column heading and data from all the 7 files.

Comment: So you just want to append the files, but remove headers in between?

Comment: Why don't you just edit your main Perl script to print to one file instead of 7 different?

Comment: Amon - yes, just append and remove header

Comment: TLP - I am picking up a script off someone who no longer works with me. The system I am pulling the data from only allows one report extraction via odbc per connection, so I have looped the script to produce the individual files. These individual files are required by other users but I also require a combined file.

Comment: Do you also want to remove duplicates, if the same row occurs in more than one file?

Comment: @user2641999 And it is impossible to edit your main script so that it, for example, when doing this: `print $somefile $somedata` also does `print $allfile $somedata`? So that you get 8 output files instead of 7. Other than that, if your columns align you can probably use some simple *nix "paste" command to merge the files.

Comment: Choroba - I do not want to remove duplicates

Comment: TLP - My plan was to put this merge script in the main script and then have the 7 separate files and the one combined file.

Comment: To properly put this in the main program, you should start with the raw data. Not data that has already been converted to CSV.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are on some kind of Unix, you can use `tail`.

```
$ tail -qn +2 fileA fileB ...
```

The `-q` supresses filenames in the output; the `-n +2` starts output with the 2nd line.

To get the header as well:

```
$ (head -n 1 fileA; tail -qn +2 fileA fileB ...) > output-file
```

If you need to use Perl:

```
use strict; use warnings; use autodie;
my $files = $#ARGV; # get number of files - 1
while (my $file = shift @ARGV) {
  open my $fh, "<", $file;
  <$fh> unless $files == @ARGV; # discard header unless first file
  print while <$fh>; # output the rest
}
```

Then: `$ perl the-script.pl fileA fileB ...`